# Get referer when using rails as an API application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I have an API and want to store referrer, however if I do things like request.referer or  request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] I get the url of the api application and not the caller.

Do I gave to catch it before in some kind of middleware ?

Just to sum it up :

**http://www.website.com** calls **GET http://www.api.com/ressource** and I want to store www.website.com as referrer in the API application.

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP_REFERER is an HTTP header set by the browser in the request containing the the address of the previous web page from which a link to the currently requested page was followed. It will not be set when directly navigating to a page.

when we are requesting API, we have to set HTTP_REFERER into Request Header.

For example,

Calling from http://client.com to http://api.com then Set HTTP_REFERER to http://client.com

Hope this helpful to you.